# Function returns None instead raising Exception

Tags: python, exception

I have the next code and it works well.

```
class AggregateException(Exception):
    pass

class Class(object):
    def some_method(self):
        ...
        try:
            if aggregate(count):
                status = Checked
        except AggregateException:
            status = Rejected
        ...

def aggregate(count):
    if <condition>:
        raise AggregateException('Invalid count')
```

But when I try to simplify logic of `some_method()` I get an unexpected result. Below you can see code

```
class Class(object):
    def some_method(self):
        ...
        self.aggregate_count(count)
        ...
    def aggregate_count(count):
        try:
            if aggregate(count):
                status = Checked
        except AggregateException:
            status = Rejected
```

When an error occurs in `aggregate_count()`, `some_method()` continues to run instead finish.

Comment: Throw `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` at the top of `aggregate_count` and step through it.  Or pepper it with some `print`s to see where the unexpected behavior occurs.

Comment: If you have catch the exception, it looks normal that the `some_method` continues to run

Comment: You are catching the exception in `aggegate_count()` function, so it catches the exception and continues execution after that block. What else are you expecting?

Comment: You are missing the `self` argument on the `aggregate_count` method. May or may not cause the problem, but it's an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what do you want to do. But as far as I understood you'd like to keep the program running if an exception occur. And that's what your script is doing. The `except`statement catches your exception and preventing your program from crashing (and change `status`). Thereafter the rest of the `some_method`-function is executed. If you want to see it on the command line simply print it in the except block.

If you'd like to crash your program and print the exception to the command line, remove the `try` and `except` statement.

Hope that helps.